# suppress output in data.table j function

Tags: r, plot, data.table, correlation

I would like to plot some `ccf` plots for different values of an `id` variable in a `data.table` using `R`. The issue is that `ccf` returns a value that doesn't agree with `data.table`. I don't care about the return value but just want to see the actual plot. Some code:

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(id=rep(1:10, each=10), a=rep(1:10,10), b=rep(10:1,10))
x[,ccf(a,b),by=id]
Error in `[.data.table`(x, , ccf(a, b), by = id) : 
All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given this in the question :

> I don't care about the return value but just want to see the actual plot.

then :

```
x[, {ccf(a,b);NULL}, by=id]
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand the question, then. I wondering if this could solve the difficulties I was having a couple of years ago when I tried something complex as a "functional" j-return  in data.table.

Comment: @DWin Not sure what you mean by functional j-return, but `j={}` has been there since the beginning (no magic, just thanks to R). In fact one reason data.table is fast is because `j` _isn't_ a function call. The FAQs use `j={}` in several places. As an aside, you can have functions in columns and look up which function to call depending on data. So that could be what you're referring to, too.

Comment: That seems even more complex than what I was hoping to be able to do. Maybe I should just look up a bunch of solved problems that I do understand and then put them in the fire until red hot, and bang on them with data.table tools.

Comment: @DWin Ha, maybe. Only if those solutions have some flaws; e.g. if they're ugly or don't scale. data.table isn't a silver bullet, though. v1.8.4 now on CRAN btw.

Answer (score 3):

This seems rather ugly by it does (eventually) return a matrix:

```
xl <- x[,list(ccf(a,b)),by=id] # ugly mess
sapply(seq(1, 60, by=6), function(vecid) xl[[2]][[vecid]] )  # nice neat matrix
```

This might be more beautiful:

```
xl <- x[ , ccf(a,b)$acf, by=id]
xl
     id          V1
  1:  1  0.37575758
  2:  1  0.25757576
  3:  1  0.07878788
  4:  1 -0.14848485
  5:  1 -0.41212121
 ---               
126: 10 -0.41212121
127: 10 -0.14848485
128: 10  0.07878788
129: 10  0.25757576
130: 10  0.37575758
```

Comment: yeh that's what i ended up doing. was hoping there was something better but i guess not

Comment: @Alex If you were hoping for something better, why accept in 23 mins?  That's only 8 mins after the minimum 15 mins.  It's 23:33 my time. Could you possibly give me 24hours?

Comment: Don't worry, @MatthewDowle, you can have any of these points you want. What sort of magic are you anticipating?

Comment: @DWin It's not the points. It's the closure. By accepting it removes it from people's view. I'm concerned about correctness not points.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: sorry about that! just seemed like somebody else tried it and might have not found anything. will wait more next time!

Comment: @Alex No problem, that will be much appreciated. There is something magical about that big green tick mark that people _believe_. And generally, askers appear to be very reluctant to move that big green tick mark later.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: yes, good point. i find myself looking at the check marked answer most of the time too.

Comment: @DWin: sorry about that, his answer is very succinct so in the spirit of people finding this i accepted his.

Comment: No need to apologize. We are all in debt to Matthew for all his data.table work.